# Python beautifulsoup and .append

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

How do I use beautifulsoup to append text to a tag with a specific id? For instance, I have the text:

```
Answer = "blah blah blah"
```

And I wish to append it to the following tag (with id="Answer") in a html file:

```
<p id="Answer">..Your answer goes here..</p>
<p>Some other text that should not be changed</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
a = """<html><body><p id="Answer">..Your answer goes here..</p>
<p>Some other text that should not be changed</p></body></html>"""
Answer = "blah blah blah"
soup = BeautifulSoup(a)

answerTag = soup.find("p", {"id":"Answer"})
answerTag.string = Answer
print soup
```